# binding an id passed through button to data in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button, append

I have a table with rows. In each row is a button that is specific to that row of data through the value of the data's id.

When a button in a specific row is clicked it fires the AJAX function `'options'`. If that is successful then I want to append the data from `$newElement` to the row in which that button is located.  The row is not always the same however so I cant just give it a tr#.

In the code below I have the append working with that data I want but it appends it to every row, not limited to the specific row and that button's id. What am I doing wrong?

AJAX/jQuery where I am appending the data from `$newElement` but am having trouble binding the id from the button. As a result it adds the data from `$newElement` to every row instead of ONLY the row in which I clicked the button.

```
function options(id){
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'post',url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
data: {action: 'options_function',cid : id_In},      
success: function (data) {
var $id = id
var $newElement=jQuery("<tr>",
{id:'ideal_option'+id,html:data})
jQuery('#list-table tr').append($newElement)}
});
}
```

The button and its initial table are generated with a combo of jQuery and HTML. This function is launched on page load. :

```
function Pop(){ ?>  
<script>    
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({ data: {action: 'list_ct'},
    type: 'post',  url: my_ajax.ajax_url,dataType: 'JSON', success: function(data) {
    var lnth = data.length-1;jQuery.each( data, function( i, val ) {
    console.log(val);           
    jQuery('<tr><td>'+val.Customer_FName+'&nbsp;'+val.Customer_LName+'<br></td><td class="tdid_'+val.id+'">'+val.Status+'</td><td><button id="options" href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" onclick="options('+val.id+')" data-id="'+val.id+'"></button></td></tr>');      
});     
}       
});     
}); 
</script>   
<table id='list-header'>     
<th>Name</th>
<tbody id='list-table'>     
</tbody>    
</table>    
<?php   
}
```

Comment: `jQuery('#list-table tr')` selects all of the rows in the table body. If you want to select a single row, narrow your selector or use the `filter` function to filter to the appropriate row. I suggest adding an ID to the row.

Comment: Thats it isnt about a single row but binding the data to that specific row based on the id. How would I do that? The row isnt a static row but changes based on its data so I cant just add an ID to the row if that makes sense

Comment: Instead of `.append('<tr><td>'+val.Customer_FNa...` use something like `.append('<tr id="row-' + i + '"><td>'+val.Customer_FNa...` Then instead of `jQuery('#list-table tr')`, just use `$newElement.insertAfter('#row-' + id)`

Comment: Thanks so much. I updated the post for clarity. That is actually the wrong spot in the appending though. That is a different table that is having data appended elsewhere. The focus of the code is in the ajax function since that is what I am trying to append. I am also unclear how the above would know which row it is with the id

Comment: Well, I can only go by the code presented and what you've said about it. Which ain't much... Use `$newElement.insertAfter(jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr'))` and forget the appending stuff then.

Comment: I updated the post for clarity. I had a previous post on this subject and got yelled at and insulted for posting too much of the code. Thus I tried this time to provide less. If I dont append, then how am I adding the new data, through the insert?

Comment: Yeah, that inserts the new row after the row with the button in it.

Comment: Thanks - forgive me but I am not familiar with that method. Yuo suggested not appending the data so I presume I remove `var $id = id
var $newElement=jQuery("<tr>",
{id:'ideal_option'+id,html:data})
jQuery('#list-table tr').append($newElement)}` portion of the code and replace it with `$newElement.insertAfter(jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr')) `inside the `success`?

Comment: The `insertAfter` replaces only the `append` line (otherwise there'd be no `$newElement` variable :)).

Comment: That is what I thought but got an `undefined :$newelement` error when using - `jQuery('#list-table tr').$newElement.insertAfter(jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr'))`

Comment: Yeah, remove `jQuery('#list-table tr').` from the beginning.

Comment: ah i see! If you want to post that as the answer, I can accept. That solves such a mystery that has plagued me for 3 days. I so appreciate it. Now to figure out why the inserted data places the header and the data in the same row!